# How to handle login users when use maxInstances for webdriverio

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

Now I try to update webdriverio's **maxInstances** > 1 for our product automation test, but I cannot find a good way to make the different test instances use different user to run test. Sometimes different instances will use the same user to login, it will cause the first login instance session timeout.

Anybody knows how to lock/unlock user for this kind of scenario？

Comment: Hi Benjamin, Could you please provide some more information of your issue. You want to login with different user on a single session(may be by clearing the opened browser cache and cookie)? Maybe you can try explain what you do when trying manually.

Comment: Sounds more like you are having problems organising your test case logic, hooks, or some concurrency issues. Like @NaveenThiyagarajan suggested above, edit your question adding relevant code snippets.

Comment: Now I just lock/unlock the users before run suite. Please refer here for more details: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/4665

Answer (score 1):

**Let me get this straight:** you are trying to run multiple instances, and have different parameters for each worker being spawned, right? (e.g: *in your case use different, non-conflicting user accounts for the flows being run*). Doesn't it seem like you [zugzwang](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Zugzwang)'ed yourself?

---

In theory, every test cases should have these three characteristics:

- small
- atomic
- autonomous

---

**❒ Possible solutions:**

1. Wait for [wdio-shared-store-service](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/pull/4663) to be reviewed > approved > merged > released

This can take a week, or it can take a month, or several months. It might not even be a feature being shipped altogether as there was quite a lot of concern around being able to share data across checks (*which people will eventually end up doing*).

Currently there is not other functionality packaged inside the framework that will allow you to achieve the same outcome. If you are able to, maybe try to look for solutions by shifting the test approach.

---

2. Reorganise your testing logic:

   - have specific test accounts associated with specific checks (*test cases*) inside your feature files (*test suites*)
   - if you want to be extremely serious about your checks being **atomic**, then have each user account created for a specific test suite (*as a test suite will only be run on one instance, per regression run*)
   - organise your test suites as such that only specific user accounts will be used for a specific run, and make your runs specific: adding the `-suite` switch to your command

---

```
  suites: {
    user: [
      './test/features/user/AnalyticsChecks.js',
      './test/features/user/SitemapChecks.js'
    ],
    superuser: [
      './test/features/superuser/HeaderChecks.js',
      './test/features/superuser/FooterChecks.js'
    ],
    admin: [
      './test/features/admin/DropUserRoles.js',
      './test/features/admin/ClearCache.js'
    ],
    batman: [
      './i/am/the/Darkness.js'
    ],
  }
```

---

3. Create your users dynamically (*pre-test, or during test run*)

If you're lucky and have access to some backend calls to push users with specific configs to the DB (*Ask for support from your Backend devs. Bring them candy!*), then ***create a script*** that produces such users,

Alternatively, you can  can create a `custom_command` that achieves the same. You call in your `before/beforeEach` hooks.

**!Note:** Don't forget to cleanup after yourself in the `after/afterEach` hooks.

**Drawbacks:**

- contradicts the **small** principle
- you won't be able to run them against PRODUCTION
- you will probably be flagged by your backend for continuously polluting the DBs with new users (*especially if you run 3-5 full regressions a day*)

You can surely find a solution to remediate this framework limitation. Be creative. Everything goes. Cheers!